# AWS OpenSearch Goggle Workspace SAML authentications

Tags: saml, google-workspace, opensearch

I have configured a custom SAML app in Google Workspace and configured AWS Opensearch to use SP-initiated SSO.

I am able to access OpenSearch via the URL but I get the following error

Missing Role
No roles available for this user, please contact your system administrator.

[image]

I guess there are some SAML attribute mapping and group set up that are required. I've created an opensearch group in Google for users that I wish to have access.

I think the following AWS Opensearch parameters require a value

SAML master backend role
Subject key
Roles key

Comment: Have you checked this? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/opensearch-dashboards-authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved using and IdP initiated authentication flow instead. The links posted in answers above helped us implement this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the issue is that you need to create a [custom attribute](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208725) inside the Admin console of Google Workspace with the "roles" for AWS Opensearch.

You can also read this information in the [AWS documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html#fgac-mapping)